# Postgres Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "channels_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(3) already exists

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

so i am getting this error whenever i try to insert a new record from this line of code:

```
Channel::insert(['customer_id' => $offer->order->user_id, 'merchant_id' => $offer->user_id, 'offer_id' => $offer->id]);
```

and this is my channels table:

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS channels_id_seq

-- Table Definition
CREATE TABLE "public"."channels" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('channels_id_seq'::regclass),
    "offer_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "customer_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "merchant_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

the sql query looks like this:

```
(SQL: insert into "channels" ("customer_id", "merchant_id", "offer_id") values (1, 3, 616))
```

i tired changing the order of variables and other things but it just doesnt seem to work

Comment: Your sequnce doesn't suit the existing data, set the nextval of the squence to max(id) + 1

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this post on resetting sequences in PostgreSQL](https://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php/how_to_fix_postgresql_error_duplicate_ke?blog=22)